# Perform selector with delay on main thread called from method running in background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nstimer, background-process

I have a method which I run in the background, by calling

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getTweets) withObject:nil];
```

'getTweets' calls a method in a wrapper class which gets the tweets and posts a notification when they're ready. I have an observer which triggers 'showTweets' when this happens.

When showTweets is called, I want to call 'hideTweets' with a delay of 5 seconds. I do this by calling:

```
self.hideTweetTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self  selector:@selector(hideTweet) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

However it doesn't seem to fire. I also have a button which calls the showTweets method, but when it's pressed it seems to get stuck in the isHighlighted state.

Since the initial call was in a background thread, am I doing something wrong?

I tried

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.hideTweetTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Which seems to work in hiding the tweet, however this seems to cause performance issues. For example, when I load a UIScrollView in a different screen, the scrolling is very sticky.

Basically, all my problems seem to arise from performing something on a background thread, but I'm not sure what... Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you modifying UI elements from those threads? The only thread that should deal with the UI is the main thread. Other threads should communicate their needs to the main thread, which will actually do it for them.

You can call something back to the main thread using:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```